# Dúvida passagem de parâmetros via formulário

Tags: php, html5

### Dúvida, não consigo enviar a imagem.

**Caminho:** _img/_produtos/foto2-verde.png

```
<input type="radio" name="cor" id="verde" value="verde"> 

<img src="_img/_produtos/foto<?=$_POST['???']?>-<?=$_POST['cor']?>.png">
```

Esse ultimo código tem que me resultar isso : **_img/_produtos/foto2-verde.png**

Do jeito que está, ele me resulta nisso: **_img/_produtos/foto**???**-verde.png**

Answer (score 0):

Ai so está a dizer que o teu ID passado por post é indefinido (não existe), mas isso é normal, pois tu só estás a passar a 'cor'

se quiseres fazer o upload de uma imagem irás ter de usar um 'input' do tipo 'file' e depois no php iras ter de utilizar $_FILE['nomeDoTeuInputFile'], já para nao falar que irás ter de utilizar o atributo enctype com o valor multipart/form-data no teu form

Comment: então, não é isso que quero, basicamente seria isso aqui.
Como passar numero como parâmetro?
para ficar correto foto2-verde.png

Comment: Editei o Tópico, dá uma olhada, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

### Resolvi o problema, a solução esta abaixo:

**Basta adicionar um input type hidden**

```
<input type="hidden" name="numproduto" value="2">
```

**E complementar o código de exibição:**

```
<img src="_img/_produtos/foto<?=$_POST['numproduto']?>-<?=$_POST['cor']?>.png"
            class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
```